# Nest Hello door bell

Tags: troubleshooting

Installed. Camera works ok. Will not chime. Checked voltage at button. 17 volts. Checked voltage at chime with Nest connectors removed. 0 voltage. Replaced Nest Hello at door with old door button. Chimes work fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried talking to Nest tech support? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I am wondering if the nest is dragging the voltage down below the value needed to make the chime work. Is it a mechanical chime? Electronic chime?  I have seen problems when the transformer was not large enough 24v at 40va , and yours sounds smaller possibly 12-15v at 10-20va I say this because an unloaded transformer will usually have a voltage reading above the stamped value.

Comment: Mechanical type. Nest claims 16 volt should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes I have visited with Nest support.